# How to test a log4j2 custom logger contained in a Spring Boot component

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have a Spring Boot `@Component` that contains a static custom logger and I need to test the log messages produced inside that component. This is the component:

```
@Component
public class CustomComponent {

  private static CustomLogger logger = CustomLogger.getLogger(CustomComponent.class);

  public void setLogger(CustomLogger logger) {
    CustomComponent.logger = logger;
  }

  public void doSomething(){
    logger.info("This is a test from CustomComponent");
  }

}
```

And this is the CustomLogger (this code is simplified. In the reality we need a custom logger because we need to do other things inside of it, but they are irrelevant for this problem):

```
public class CustomLogger {

  private final ExtendedLoggerWrapper log;

  private CustomLogger(final Logger log) {
    this.log = new ExtendedLoggerWrapper((AbstractLogger) log, log.getName(), log.getMessageFactory());
  }

  public static synchronized CustomLogger getLogger(final Class<?> clazz) {
      final Logger wrapped = LogManager.getLogger(clazz);
      return new CustomLogger(wrapped);
  }

  public void info(Object message) {
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
      log.info(message);
    }
  }
}
```

#### log4j2.xml Configuration

This is the log4j2 file:

```
<Configuration status="warn" name="CustomLogger" packages="">

  <Appenders>
    <List name="List1" />
    <Console name="APPLICATION" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %5p %m (%F:%L)%n"/>
      <Filters>
        <!-- This allows DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR AND FATAL -->
        <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      </Filters>
    </Console>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.example.demo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="List1" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

#### JUnit configuration

In my JUnit class I have `@Autowired` the component, and I have the `ListAppender` retrieved using `LoggerContextRule`. In the `setup()` I create a `mockLogger` that I pass to the `CustomComponent` using a setter. 
 This is the code of my JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  CustomComponent component;

  @ClassRule
  public static LoggerContextRule context = new LoggerContextRule("log4j2.xml");
  private ListAppender listAppender;


  @Before
  public void setup(){
    CustomLogger mockLogger = CustomLogger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    component.setLogger(logger);
    listAppender = context.getListAppender("List1").clear();
  }

    @Test
    public void testCustomComponent() {
      component.doSomething();
    final List<LogEvent> events = listAppender.getEvents();
    assertThat(events, hasSize(1));
    }
}
```

I was expecting the `listAppender` to record the events in the `mockLogger`, but instead it's empty and the test fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection with size <1>
     but: collection size was <0>
```

I do not understand what error I am doing, whether it's a problem of context - which may be different in the JUnit class and in the @Component - or something else.

I have spent a huge amount of time trying to read the official documentation of log4j2, or trying to find similar problems here on Stackoverflow, but without success.

#### Update

Solution found. Sometimes just writing down your problem and trying to summarize it, you get the epiphany. I forgot to add the `<AppenderRef ref="List1">` in the right logger. It was set only in the root logger and that's why it was not working.

Comment: What listAppender.getEvents(); returning?

Comment: a `Collection$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` with `size` = 0.

Comment: Basically the `List<LogEvent> events` is empty.

Comment: That is why you are getting error.

Comment: Yes. My question is why this List is empty.

Comment: Where is the code for getEvents() ?

Comment: I found the solution. Sometimes just writing down your problem and trying to summarize it, you get the epiphany. 

I forgot to add the `<AppenderRef>` in the right logger, in the `log4j2.xml` file. It was only in the Root logger.